# Background color of menu item when Dropdown menu is still active

Tags: html, jquery, css, shopify

I would like to simulate as if the menu item is connected to the dropdown menu whenever this is active by changing the background color.

How can I change the background of the "Catalogo" menu item whenever the dropdown menu is active?

I have been able to get the background color to change as I hover over the menu item using this code:

```
.site-nav__link--button:focus, .site-nav__link--button:hover {
  background-color: #B8A899;}
```

[This is my website.](https://t7ca0ibxg62uvs0i-51451003036.shopifypreview.com)

I am extremely new to CSS/HTML, and I have no idea what the relevant code would be to produce a minimal working example.

Can someone point me into the right direction? Where could I modify my code to produce the desired behaviour?

**EDIT:**
This is the effect I want to achieve, and I want the background color to remain as I move the mouse cursor through the dropdown menu:
[image]

Comment: Do you want the hover to apply even when the mouse cursor is over the dropdown menu? Is that the problem? - https://ibb.co/zF3gxXN

Comment: Yes. I want the background color to remain as I move the mouse cursor over the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this appeal.

```
li.site-nav--has-dropdown:hover {
     background-color: #B8A899;
}
```